# Reaction Workup and Quenching

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, purification

In the [supporting information](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/suppl/10.1021/acs.orglett.6b00799/suppl_file/ol6b00799_si_001.pdf) of [synthetic paper by Buchwald's group](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.orglett.6b00799), They use 2-MeTHF as solvent (See B. General Procedures for Amination part, page 8). After the reaction ends and cools the mixture to room temperature, they dilute it using dichloromethane.

Question 1: Why do they use dichloromethane, instead of 2-MeTHF which is the solvent of the reaction? Any particular reason? Also I have seen another paper that Buchwald's group also used dichloromethane in prior to filtration, and in that paper they used toluene as solvent.

Question 2: What is 'kinetic' quench? I searched for it literally in Google, but I couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: I have never heard the phrase "kinetic quench". As for the procedure there may be not stronger reason than DCM is the preferred solvent within the group - it works so don't fix it.

Comment: @Waylander What I wonder is why they used other solvent instead of original solvent, 2-MeTHF. If the purpose is quenching, I don't think that addition of just another solvent may quit the reaction.

Comment: Or, perhaps they mean 'kinetic' quench that by diluting the mixture so lowering the reaction rate? If so, but still I don't understand why they did not use original solvent.

Comment: 2-Me-THF is a lot more expensive than DCM so it may simply be a cost issue